# Passing unserialized elements to View

Tags: php, arrays, session, view, laravel

I'm storing an array of elements in the PHP session. The thing is, when I try to access the elements of this array directly from the view, the object is not complete and I cannot access it's properties.

The solution I came up with was to serialize the elements before inserting them into the array. And just before calling my view, I create a new array with the same elements that were in the session but unserialized.

```
$elements = Session::get('elements');
$elements_unserialized = array();

if($elements != null)
{
    foreach ($elements as $element)
    {
        array_push($elements_unserialized, unserialize($element));
    }
}

return View::make('home')->with('elements', $elements_unserialized);
```

I was wondering if someone had a better solution.

I'm using Laravel, by the way.

Comment: I am a little confused by your question... Wouldn't having access to the session array from the view be the ideal solution?  Is there a particular reason for serializing it?  I ask because you should be able to just pass the array to the view or just access the session directly from the view.  Let me know about the serializing thing and we can go from there.

Comment: Why you can't directly access the `elements` from the `view`?

Comment: elements is an array with objects, lets say Cars. If I try to access $element->engine directly in the view, I get an error saying that the object is incomplete. Basically, when I insert the car into an array, and then that array into the session, I seem to lose the possibility of accessing each car's properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with sessions you need to serialize() and unserialize() the complete array, not its elements.